# Consolidating project sites in Azure DevOps - issue moving test work items

Tags: azure-devops, test-suite, workitem

The number of project sites in our organisation grew to a ridiculous level.  We've tried to consolidate related projects into one site and have different areas so that projects can have their own board.

Where we are encountering a few difficulties is trying to consolidate projects with test suites, test cases, etc. and have had the following message.

> Work item type Test Suite cannot be moved because it is disabled,
> hidden or not supported in the source project

Has anyone got any advice on how I can overcome this?  Not sure that the source project is the problem since the work items I want to move are already there... but it may be my lack of understanding of the process...?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to move the work item, You can only move work items from one project to another project within the organization or collection. You can’t move work items associated with test management. So this means we can only move like bug, task, feature, user story, Epic or some customer task. But we can not move the test case. For more details, you can refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops#move-a-work-item-to-another-project

[image]

Comment: That's disappointing but grateful for your steer - I'd prefer not to lose the info, but I also don't know enough about the work items for test management.  Are there reports (in whatever format) that can be run/exported that I could save them in our document management solution instead? I'd assume that I could replicate the items, but not sure how (or even if it's possible) I would go about capturing the test results.

Comment: Hello, instead of moving a work item linked with test management, direct copy Test Suites and Test Cases are supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/copy-clone-test-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Also, you could export test data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/reference-qa?view=azure-devops#can-i-just-view-test-plan-data-i-export--or-copy-it-to-a-word-document